# Instantaiting a variable with a object turns the object into a function, then the objects data members return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

```
var a = [function (){this.af = "DDS"}]
var b  = a[0] 
a[0] = new a[0]
console.log(typeof a[0], a[0].af, typeof b, b.af)
```

Output: object DDS function undefined

Why does b have a different value then a[0]? Why does b.af return undefined when a[0].af returns "DDS"?

Comment: Because `b` is a reference to the function, `a[0]` is an instance of the JS "class". The array here just adds noise, you could have the same result without it: `function a(){this.af = "DDS"};var b  = a;a = new a;console.log(typeof a, a.af, typeof b, b.af);`. Did you mean to use `var b =  new a[0]`?

Comment: I wrote this down wrong. sorry. what I meant to say is, I have a list of objects. they were functions till I initialized them. In the web console it shows them as functions with the view minimized, but then when I click the notch to have it expand it shows them as objects. When I do typeof it shows them as function. Why would something be shown as a function when it is a object

Comment: In Chrome or Firefox, `console.log` of objects (which includes functions and arrays since they are objects) displays a compacted version of the object when `console.log` is called, but displays the current value of the object [when expanded the first time.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Parameters) This seems to be causing confusion. If you want to log information as it exists at the time of logging, convert the information into a string and log the string, not the object.

Comment: Are you really asking "If I take a copy of an an entry in an array, and then change the value of the entry in the array, why does the copy not get updated as well?"

Comment: No I am not asking that, but thank you for insight into web browser. Ok, so I am trying to explain my problem without the context. So here is the problem. I have a array of annoynomes functions that are constructors. I loop through the array and construct each function into a object using new. Then it shows the objects when I print the array with the data members. BUT when I do type of on a element of the list it says function, AND most importantly when I do foo[0].dataMember it return as undefined despite showing it when I console log the list

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve confusion we can try step by step console.logging them to know what happened.

```
var a = [function (){this.af = "DDS"}]; // a is an array with function declaration as first element
var b  = a[0]; //b is now a function declaration. **Without running nor executing it**
a[0] = new a[0] //By running new a[0] we are creating an instance and 
                //we replaced with the first element of array

console.log(typeof a[0], a[0].af, typeof b, b.af)

a[0] is now an instance //{af: 'DDS'}
a[0].af === 'DDS'
b is still a function declaration
b.af will be undefined because b doesn't have a property `af`
```

Comment: I wrote this down wrong. sorry. what I meant to say is, I have a list of objects. they were functions till I initialized them. In the web console it shows them as functions with the view minimized, but then when I click the notch to have it expand it shows them as objects. When I do typeof it shows them as function. Why would something be shown as a function when it is a object

Comment: also note that it is undefined to get a data member from the objects after defined